# new to java - code to list duplicates need to be optimized

Tags: java, android

the following code does the following: for each element in 'a', find if it has match in element 'b':

```
String a[] = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
String b[] = new String[]{"e","f","a","a"};
String hold=""; 

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){


for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++){

     if ( a[i].equals( b[k])  ){
        hold+=a[i];

     }//if

}//for


}//for
```

the problem is that sometimes array 'b' can contain duplicates, but we do not want
duplicates to be recorded in the variable 'hold'

Here is what i have tried - save all matches to a HashSet, then use the containsKey() to first
check it is in the hashset, if not, then update the 'hold' variable. Have also tried to record each match in an array and first check this array before updating the 'hold' variable

Is there another way to do this? Is there a more optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a break so you leave the for as soon as you get an object that matches

```
for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++){

     if ( a[i].equals( b[k])  ){
        hold+=a[i];
        break;
     }//if

}//for
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to stop the other for too do it like this:

```
    start:
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){


        for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++){

            if ( a[i].equals( b[k])  ){
                hold+=a[i];
                break start;
            }//if

        }//for


    }//for
```

**EDIT**

If you want to make sure you don't get the "a" duplicates do this:

```
String a[] = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
String b[] = new String[]{"e", "f", "a", "a"};
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

String hold = "";

for (String anA : a)
    if (!matches.contains(anA))
        for (String aB : b)
            if (anA.equals(aB))
            {
                hold += anA;
                matches.add(anA);
            }//if
    }//for


}//for
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Add a label and break the label you defined.

Comment: Also if you are going to check if there are duplicates in 'a' too then a for is not the best solution and you should use the other ones already shown here by other people :)

Comment: your second solution does not work, for example:String a[] = new String[]{"c","a","a","e"};
String b[] = new String[]{"a","c"};      output is only c. which is  wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [a Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) for your hold variable so that it doesn't contain duplicates, and use the `retainAll` method to get the intersection between a set and another collection (which can contain duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

I would convert them to a List and use [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) to find the matches.  Then just loop the list for your hold var.  You don't have to worry about duplicates in b using this method.  retainAll will not care that it is in b twice.  It will retain a because it existed in b.  Whatever is left in the a Array will get concatenated into your hold.

```
String a[] = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
String b[] = new String[]{"e","f","a","a"};

//get new ArrayList because asList is immutable
List<String> aList = new ArrayList(Collections.asList(a));
List<String bList = Collections.asList(b);

aList.retainAll(bList);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : aList) {
    sb.append(s);
}

String hold = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Yeah, this is basically what I mentioned earlier with the code snippet. gj :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a sets would automatically remove duplicates.

```
Set< String > mySet1 = new HashSet< String >(Arrays.asList(a));
Set< String > mySet2 = new HashSet< String >(Arrays.asList(b));
```

`mySet1` or `mySet2` would not contain any duplicates.
According to your example `mySet1` would be `{"a","b","c"}` and `mySet2` would be `{"e","f","a"}`

After this point you can use multiple methods to get where you want check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) documentation.
I believe you are looking for removeAll function.

Answer (score 0):

using java.util.List is easy:

```
List<String> listB = new LinkedList();
    for(int i = 0; i < b.lenght; i++) listB.add(b[i]);
    for(int i = 0; i < a.lenght; i++) {

        if(listB.contains(a[i])) hold+=a[i];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, what i see you are doing, is you have 2 arrays with content in it. I understand the content is going to be different in the future. Every time you iterate through 1 character of array A, you want to test if array B has a equal value. If so you want to store that value ONCE in the array/string Hold.

Why not just check in hold if the value already exists, and if not, add it, if so, skip it?

PS: Sorry I did not do this in the comments, but I do not have enough rep to comment on the issue itself.